# Doctrine2 / Symfony2: One-Way Many-to-Many Query with Left Join

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am relatively new to Doctrine, but fairly proficient in SQL. I can't seem to effectively convert the following MySQL query to Doctrine in a Symfony 2.3 application:

```
select 
    asset.id as asset_id, 
    orgAsset.organization_id,
    districtAsset.district_id,
    deptAsset.department_id,
    subjectAsset.subject_id,
    schoolAsset.school_id,
    teacherAsset.teacher_id,
    sectionAsset.section_id,
    syllabusAsset.syllabus_id 
from asset
left join organizations_assets orgAsset on asset.id = orgAsset.asset_id
left join districts_assets districtAsset on asset.id = districtAsset.asset_id
left join departments_assets deptAsset on asset.id = deptAsset.asset_id
left join subjects_assets subjectAsset on asset.id = subjectAsset.asset_id
left join schools_assets schoolAsset on asset.id = schoolAsset.asset_id
left join teachers_assets teacherAsset on asset.id = teacherAsset.asset_id
left join sections_assets sectionAsset on asset.id = sectionAsset.asset_id
left join syllabus_assets syllabusAsset on asset.id = syllabusAsset.asset_id
where asset.id = ?;
```

All the `*_assets` tables are one-way many-to-many tables with the `*` objects joined to `Asset` objects.

My first goal is to just get this kind of query to work using Doctrine. My end-goal is for Doctrine to return only the objects that are associated with the asset. Here is an example of my one-way many-to-many object mapping. There is no reciprocal mapping in the `Asset` object:

```
class Organization
{
...
       /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Asset")
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="organizations_assets",
         *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="organization_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)},
         *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="asset_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
         *      )
         *
         * @var ArrayCollection|Asset[]
         */
        protected $assets;

...
}
```

The objects that extend `Asset` are too complex to realistically refactor to single table inheritance.

Is the one-way mapping the issue? Am I going to need to create a native query to handle this? I find it difficult to believe that Doctrine can't natively handle this, so I hope I'm overlooking something simple.

Comment: So it appears you've implemented [classTableInheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)  See the section on support for that pattern in the [inheritance mapping chapter](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

Comment: @gview, I've implemented inheritance mapping on assets, but not on the  organizational objects joined with the assets. The inheritance is working just fine on the assets. Thank you for the advice, though. Re-reading that chapter was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm learning more about Doctrine, there is a simple reason this does not work. There are no mappings in `Asset` back to any of the organizational entities. In other words, while an `Organization` has `Assets`, an `Asset` does not have an `Organization`, `School`, `District`, etc..

As I see it, here are a couple of solutions to this problem:

1) Create the association to each organizational object in `Asset`. This is not sexy, and may be inefficient.

2) Create an `AssetContainer` and leverage inheritance (probably single-table) for each organizational object. This is sexy, but would involve some refactoring. It would look something like this:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"organization" = "OrganizationAsset", "district" = "DistrictAsset"})
 */
class AssetContainer
{
    protected $id;
    protected $asset;  // join to Asset
}

class OrganizationAsset extends AssetContainer
{
    protected $organization; // join to Organization
}

class DistrictAsset extends AssetContainer
{
    protected $district; // join to District
}

class Asset
{
    ...
    protected $assetContainers; // join to AssetContainer
    ...
}
```

3) Run a simple SQL query (see OP) and hydrate as necessary. Not quite as sexy as #2, but a good quick-fix without refactoring.

I'm pretty sure I'm going with #2 or #3. If I go with #2, I will report back on the results.